# Issue with Django Static Files 3.1

Tags: python, django, static, django-staticfiles

Django is looking for my static files in the wrong place and I dont understand why

```sh
Not Found: /account/login/style.css
[26/Feb/2021 19:27:16] "GET /account/login/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2434
```

but my file should be in `/static/css/style.css`

This is the code in my **settings.py**:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]
```

I use `staticfiles` folder to place my static files afterwards I do `py src\manage.py collectstatic` to transfer my files in `static` folder

This is my layout of the project:

[image]

In my template I am using `{% load static %}` and I try to load the style.css with `{% static 'css/style.css' %}`

Here is the **urls.py** in `core`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('account/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    # test mode
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**urls.py** in `accounts`:

```py
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="registration/login.html",
                                                authentication_form=UserLoginForm), name='login'),
]
```

Login page is the one that I have the problem with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/`

`Template`:
[image]

`DEBUG` is **true** in settings

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Please show your template where you refer the css file.

Comment: I added a photo in the post

Comment: Write only `{% static 'css/style.css' %}` unless you have a static folder inside the static folder which has the css. Also in this page search using ctrl + F for `login/style.css` or something.

Comment: it was a mistake when i wrote {% static 'static/css/style.css' %} I changed it and it didnt work

Comment: Check that you have not accidentally redefined `STATIC_URL` in your settings perhaps you wanted to set `LOGIN_URL` and redefined `STATIC_URL`?

Comment: I checked and there's nothing like that

Comment: It seems like I was editing the wrong `login` file .... What a waste of time. I am sorry bro....